# cannot find symbol RunAction2

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, plugins

right now I am trying to learn pluginprogramming for Jenkins. I started off with the Hello World tutorial, which can be found [here](https://jenkins.io/doc/developer/tutorial/prepare/).

```
java version: 1.8
maven version: 3.5.2
OS: windows 7
```

The basic Hello World plugins works fine for me, but at the last [step](https://jenkins.io/doc/developer/tutorial/extend/), where adding a side panel, I always get following error as soon as I try to `mvn verify`:

```
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 17.570 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-02-06T08:34:41+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 48M/892M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.
6.1:compile (default-compile) on project demo: Compilation failure: Compilation
failure:
[ERROR] /C:/Users/jschoene/demo/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/sample/Hello
WorldAction.java:[5,20] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class RunAction2
[ERROR]   location: package hudson.model
[ERROR] /C:/Users/jschoene/demo/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/sample/Hello
WorldAction.java:[7,42] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol: class RunAction2
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swit
ch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureExc
eption
```

Below I listed my Code

**HelloWorldAction.java**

```
package org.jenkinsci.plugins.sample;

import hudson.model.Action;
import hudson.model.Run;
import hudson.model.RunAction2;

public class HelloWorldAction implements RunAction2 {

    private String name;
    private transient Run run;

    public HelloWorldAction(String Name) {
        this.name = Name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public String getIconFileName() {
        return "document.png";
    }

    @Override
    public String getDisplayName() {
        return "Greeting";
    }

    @Override
    public String getUrlName() {
        return "greeting";
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttached(Run<?, ?> run) {
        this.run = run; 
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoad(Run<?, ?> run) {
        this.run = run; 
    }

    public Run getRun() { 
        return run;
    }
}
```

**HelloWorldBuilder.java**

```
package org.jenkinsci.plugins.sample;

import hudson.Launcher;
import hudson.Extension;
import hudson.FilePath;
import hudson.util.FormValidation;
import hudson.model.AbstractProject;
import hudson.model.Run;
import hudson.model.TaskListener;
import hudson.tasks.Builder;
import hudson.tasks.BuildStepDescriptor;
import org.kohsuke.stapler.DataBoundConstructor;
import org.kohsuke.stapler.QueryParameter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import java.io.IOException;
import jenkins.tasks.SimpleBuildStep;
import org.jenkinsci.Symbol;
import org.kohsuke.stapler.DataBoundSetter;

public class HelloWorldBuilder extends Builder implements SimpleBuildStep {

    private final String name;
    private boolean useFrench;

    @DataBoundConstructor
    public HelloWorldBuilder(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public boolean isUseFrench() {
        return useFrench;
    }

    @DataBoundSetter
    public void setUseFrench(boolean useFrench) {
        this.useFrench = useFrench;
    }

    @Override
    public void perform(Run<?, ?> run, FilePath workspace, Launcher launcher, TaskListener listener) throws InterruptedException, IOException {
        run.addAction(new HelloWorldAction(name));
        if (useFrench) {
            listener.getLogger().println("Bonjour, " + name + "!");
        } else {
            listener.getLogger().println("Hello, " + name + "!");
        }
    }

    @Symbol("greet")
    @Extension
    public static final class DescriptorImpl extends BuildStepDescriptor<Builder> {

        public FormValidation doCheckName(@QueryParameter String value, @QueryParameter boolean useFrench)
                throws IOException, ServletException {
            if (value.length() == 0)
                return FormValidation.error(Messages.HelloWorldBuilder_DescriptorImpl_errors_missingName());
            if (value.length() < 4)
                return FormValidation.warning(Messages.HelloWorldBuilder_DescriptorImpl_warnings_tooShort());
            if (!useFrench && value.matches(".*[éáàç].*")) {
                return FormValidation.warning(Messages.HelloWorldBuilder_DescriptorImpl_warnings_reallyFrench());
            }
            return FormValidation.ok();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isApplicable(Class<? extends AbstractProject> aClass) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public String getDisplayName() {
            return Messages.HelloWorldBuilder_DescriptorImpl_DisplayName();
        }

    }

}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.jenkins-ci.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.33</version>
        <relativePath />
    </parent>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>hpi</packaging>
    <properties>
        <!-- Baseline Jenkins version you use to build the plugin. Users must have this version or newer to run. -->
        <jenkins.version>2.7.3</jenkins.version>
        <!-- Other properties you may want to use:
          ~ java.level: set to 6 if your jenkins.version <= 1.611
          ~ jenkins-test-harness.version: Jenkins Test Harness version you use to test the plugin. For Jenkins version >= 1.580.1 use JTH 2.0 or higher.
          ~ hpi-plugin.version: The HPI Maven Plugin version used by the plugin..
          ~ stapler-plugin.version: The Stapler Maven plugin version required by the plugin.
     -->
    </properties>
    <name>TODO Plugin</name>
    <description>TODO</description>
    <url>https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/TODO+Plugin</url>
    <!-- The default licence for Jenkins OSS Plugins is MIT. Substitute for the applicable one if needed. -->
    <licenses>
        <license>
            <name>MIT License</name>
            <url>http://opensource.org/licenses/MIT</url>
        </license>
    </licenses>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jenkins-ci.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>structs</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jenkins-ci.plugins.workflow</groupId>
            <artifactId>workflow-step-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jenkins-ci.plugins.workflow</groupId>
            <artifactId>workflow-cps</artifactId>
            <version>2.39</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jenkins-ci.plugins.workflow</groupId>
            <artifactId>workflow-job</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jenkins-ci.plugins.workflow</groupId>
            <artifactId>workflow-basic-steps</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jenkins-ci.plugins.workflow</groupId>
            <artifactId>workflow-durable-task-step</artifactId>
            <version>2.13</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jenkins-ci.plugins.workflow</groupId>
            <artifactId>workflow-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.20</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jenkins-ci.plugins.workflow</groupId>
            <artifactId>workflow-support</artifactId>
            <version>2.14</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <!-- If you want this to appear on the wiki page:
    <developers>
      <developer>
        <id>bhacker</id>
        <name>Bob Q. Hacker</name>
        <email>bhacker@nowhere.net</email>
      </developer>
    </developers> -->

    <!-- Assuming you want to host on @jenkinsci:
    <scm>
        <connection>scm:git:git://github.com/jenkinsci/${project.artifactId}-plugin.git</connection>
        <developerConnection>scm:git:git@github.com:jenkinsci/${project.artifactId}-plugin.git</developerConnection>
        <url>https://github.com/jenkinsci/${project.artifactId}-plugin</url>
    </scm>
    -->
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>repo.jenkins-ci.org</id>
            <url>https://repo.jenkins-ci.org/public/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>repo.jenkins-ci.org</id>
            <url>https://repo.jenkins-ci.org/public/</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

**index.jelly**

```
<?jelly escape-by-default='true'?>
<j:jelly xmlns:j="jelly:core" xmlns:l="/lib/layout" xmlns:st="jelly:stapler">
    <l:layout title="Greeting"> 
        <l:side-panel>
            <st:include page="sideplay.jelly" it="${it.run}" optional="true" />
        </l:side-panel>
        <l:main-panel> 
            <h1> 
                Name: ${it.name} 
            </h1>
        </l:main-panel>
    </l:layout>
</j:jelly>
```

I checked some other threads on stackoverflow with the pattern **cannot find symbol**, and as far as I could figure out, it seems the class **RunAction2** is somehow missing. But I know from the jenkins tutorial that `mvn verify` should actually download all missing dependencies, so I dont know how I can fix that problem.

I also tried to change the JDK version in the `pom.xml` file to my actual version, that did also not help.

I guess its a quite trivial error, but as a bloody beginner I am stuck here. Hope someone can point me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Look more carefully at the tutorial - you need `import jenkins.model.RunAction2;` not `import hudson.model.RunAction2;`. **hudson** -> **jenkins**.

Comment: Ok, this post was way to long for such a stupid mistake. Anyway thank you, its working now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in the comments here is the solution:

you need import jenkins.model.RunAction2; not import hudson.model.RunAction2;. hudson -> jenkins